# How to migrate a Docker image with all its parent layers to another machine?

Tags: docker, migration

I have a Docker box where I build my images. I would like to migrate the images to another machine but I would like to also have all the layers of the images available on that new machine.

The [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/save/#extended-description) specifies that when using `docker save` the generated image contains all parent layers and tags.

I used `docker save` and then `docker load` the image on the other machine but if I'm doing a `docker history myimage` I see that all the other layers are marked as `missing`.

How then can I get the image with all its parent layers to the other machine?

Thank you.